# How can we drop multiple columns in MariaDB in one command

Tags: mariadb, alter, mariasql

I am trying to drop multiple columns in a single command.
I have tried below commands:

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1, col2;

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN (col1, col2);

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN col1, col2;

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN "col1", "col2";

ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMNS col1, col2;

P.S: None of the above worked.

Answer (score 2):

[Read the fine manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#drop-column):

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name alter_specification [, alter_specification]`

For example

```
MariaDB [test]> create table t1 (a int, b int, c int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> alter table t1 drop column a, drop column b;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```